# Display form using extension in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am a novice to magento.

#### Task at Hand

I need to create the extensions for magento.Now i need to create an extension that is used to display the form. The form values are needed to be stored in the database and  to be mailed to the admin.

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you one link will same as your requirements and it will totally free so you can use it for the reference.
http://www.magestore.com/magento-product-questions-extension.html

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.Mayur.When i try to buy or download from this link i got this error : Product Questions
This extension is no longer available.
You cannot purchase this extension any more. Contact Magestore Support Team in case you have queries relating to this  extension. How to do this  Mr.Mayur and also i need to create by own extension can you give any suggestion for this?

Comment: I have this extension but how I can give you that I don't know. If you have skype then give me.

Comment: No sir i dont have skype

Comment: Ok then give me mail id.

Comment: Mr.Mayur i want to create own extension.That  extension should contain form.Url: http://www.phpzag.com/create-custom-module-with-custom-database-table/  and http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/  .Can you please refer this url's i tired  this but i got error "there has been an error processing your request ".Based on this can you give any suggestions for me?

Comment: Hello Mam,

Please check this link it will give you custom extension with all your feature.
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can download extensions from magento connect according to your need, you can try this [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-feedback-extension.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When i try to download the extension i got this "Could not resolve host: magento-community" in the  magento connect manager.What i have to do?

Comment: use this http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php to directly download any extension just paste the extension key in text field and submit query you will see a link just above text field to download the extension thnks

Comment: using this url i download the file then i try to upload file i got this error